# An unexpected error occurred while import sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

On importing spreadsheet in SharePoint 2010, getting error

> "An unexpected error occurred".

1. Tried to add that site to trusted sites. Not worked!
2. Cannot activate visualbasic features from Add/Remove features due to admin rights.

Please suggest some alternate solution.